# How can I reverse the row order for an ADO.NET DataTable?

Tags: ado.net

I have a DataTable that I have obtained by deserializing a JSON message.  I do not know ahead of time what the column names will be so I cannot use DataView.Sort on a specific column.  I would simply like to reverse the order of the rows.  Here is what I tried:

```
var reversedTable = new DataTable();
for (var row = originalTable.Rows.Count - 1; row >= 0; row--)
    reversedTable.Rows.Add(response.Messages.Rows[row]);
```

but this throws "System.ArgumentException: This row already belongs to another table."  How can I accomplish this seemingly simple task?  Thanks in advance,

Frank

ANSWER:

```
 var reversed = original.Clone();
 for (var row = original.Rows.Count - 1; row >= 0; row--)
     reversed.ImportRow(original.Rows[row]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that error message before..... 
You're not allowed to directly add a row from one table to another. First you have to clone the table, then you can go through and call ImportRow() for each of the rows.

Check out [geekzilla](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View37EB5230-5B79-4D00-800C-52D7A46CFB15.htm) for a decent example.

I hope that helps!